# Homomorphism, range, and kernel abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm just not even sure where to start on this question.

> If $f: G \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism, prove that if the range of $f$ has $n$ elements, then $x^n$ is in $\ker f$ for every $x$ in $G$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\phi$ be the homomorphism from $G$ to $H$

Take $x\in G$ and consider $\phi(x)$, since the image or range  of $\phi$ is a subgroup of order $n$ of $H$ we know $\phi(x)^n=e_H$. But it is a fact that in homomorphisms $\phi(x)^n=\phi(x^n)$. We conclude $x^n\in \ker \phi$

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much!